# Upload sql document using terminal

Tags: mysql, sql-server, terminal

I connected to server using ssh, and I need to upload MySQL database.

I have tried:

```
$ mysql -u root -p database_name < /Users/stevik/Desktop/database.sql
-bash: /Users/stevik/Desktop/database.sql: Directory or file does not exist
```

And I have also tried:

```
mysql> source /Users/stevik/Desktop/database.sql
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'database.sql', error: 2
```

Is it trying to get the file on the server or on my computer?

Comment: You are using a path local to your computer. It does not work on a remote server. Copy the database to the server and use the local filename/path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the file database.sql to the server, use "scp" for this.  For windows, I'm fond of winscp http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: Is it safe to have it on server as .sql file ?

Comment: assuming the server is relatively secure...  you can delete it once you've imported it